# Class \Permission not found in Zizaco/entrust in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, role

I am using https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/laravel-5 to manage the role.
I have already created three roles ( 1. admin, 2. Staff, 3. User) and three permissions(1.read_data, 2.edit_data, 3.edit_user)

Now I am trying to assign permission to role. I am making a CRUD for role, so I tried like this to assign permission in my routes.php file

```
  use App\Model\Role;

  use App\Model\Permission;

  Route::get('test/', function(){

     $role = Role::find(1);
     $permission = Permission::find(1);

     $role->attachPermission($permission);
     return 'whoo';

});
```

But I am getting class \Permission not found error.

Comment: did u add the correct namespace in Permission.php ?

Comment: yes when I return $role and $permission, I am getting the data. But the problem is on attaching the permission.